# IPhone7 or 7Plus use becomeFirstResponder has a serious white-screen bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

1. Use **Xcode8** create a project
2. Now I let `ViewControllerA` pushed a new `ViewControllerB`
3. I write a code in the method `ViewDidLoad` of `ViewControllerB`

   ```
   - (void)ViewDidLoad {
       [super ViewDidLoad];

       [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   ```
4. Now I found in iPhone7 or iPhone7 plus when pushing `ViewControllerB` has a white color full screen in the window. Just fresh a mile.

I don't want to use:

```
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

on `ViewDidAppear`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this actually happening on device or just in the simulator?

Comment: I have no device.so in the simulator has the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same question in simulator, so I borrow a iphone 7 to verify that it's not happend in real devices. The fact is right, it's not
happend in real devices, so, you can ignore it. Hope it can help you.